# What do you do after you put the disc in the computer?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I got the disc and put it in the computer, the song 'The Fox' came up and I watched it. What do I do next? What is the next step in the game?

Answer (score 2):

For 'The Fox' part, that's it, it's just a little easter egg.

To actually proceed, turn on the computer and click a little dot in the 'in-game game', then you should be able to see some sand, try to bury yourself in it and you will fall down into a hole.