# How do I bury myself in the sand?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I am really confused about what I am supposed to do after I get the disc from the guy in the castle, and I heard something about burying myself in sand to fight someone. Where is this sand, and what do I do afterwards?

Comment: Do this question/answer help? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221848/what-do-you-do-after-you-put-the-disc-in-the-computer/235667#235667

Comment: I don't know how to get to the computer.